# C# - List of different types of objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a list that contains all the objects for all the different units that are spawned in my game, but they are not all the same class. They all are sub classes of the main unit class if that would help. But basically I have a main unit class with the basic functionality, then more for swordsman, pikeman, etc, and I want to beable to put all different types in one list to be able to manage them easier. Is that possible?

Comment: But, that wouldn't have the info from the sub class in it would it?

Comment: Sure it would, you can add the complete object. You have to cast it to the preferred object when retrieving it though.

Comment: It's better to create list of lists of objects. If you need traverse all objects the overhead will be very small (while traversing every list in main list) but traversing a special object type in their own list will be much faster that traversing one big list with all objects.

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is possible.

As Rob said in his comment, you need to make a `List<SharedBaseClass>`.

```
var someList = new List<SharedBaseClass>();
```

When you are trying to interact with a particular element in the List you will need to cast back to the correct sub class:

```
// throws an exception if type wrong
var someElement = (desiredSubClass) someList[someElementIndex];

// return null if type wrong
var someElement = someList[someElementIndex] as desiredSubClass;
```

Comment: Safer to do `var someElement = someList[index] as DesiredSubclass` then do a null check on `someElement`. Alternatively, `someList.OfType<DesiredSubclass>()` to get all elements os a specific derived type

Answer (score 1):

*[Slvrfn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3344317/slvrfn)*'s anwer should work fine. If you don't like casting or you care about performance hit when casting in Unity, you can also make a variable in the subclass and initialize it in the `constructor` with the `this` keyword.

Let's say you have two classes you inherit from:

```
public class FirstBase
{
    public int speed = 50;
}

public class SecondBase : FirstBase
{
    public int live = 5;
}
```

And then your subclass:

```
public class MySubClass : SecondBase
{
    public FirstBase firstBase;
    public SecondBase secondBase;

    public MySubClass()
    {
        firstBase = this;
        secondBase = this;
    }
}
```

You don't need to cast anymore. You can use the defined firstBase and secondBase variables from the `MySubClass`.

```
List<MySubClass> subClass = new List<MySubClass>();
subClass.Add(new MySubClass());

FirstBase firstBase = subClass[0].firstBase;
SecondBase secondBase = subClass[0].secondBase;
```

Comment: problem with this is I want to have a array of unit types basically, so I can call them, and they aren't all sub classes of each toher

Comment: Well, you said they are subclass in your question. TBH, if you want to have a great answer, please provide a code in your question next time. The sample you provide will tell people what you are doing.