# Add lists to another list class

Tags: c#

My code has 3 classes (a, b, c), that (b,c) classes inherit a. and I have a list (list mylist). My prblem is about adding to element from class b or class c

```
public class A
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public A(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public int z;
    public B(int x, int y, int z) : base(x, y)
    {

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myA = new List<A>();
        myA.Add(new A(1, 2));
        myA.Add(new B(3, 4, 5));
        Console.WriteLine(myA[1]); 
        Console.WriteLine("0.x=" + myA[0].x + "--0.y=" + myA[0].y);
        Console.WriteLine("1.x=" + myA[1].x + "--1.y=" + myA[1].y + "--1.z=");// I can't see myA.z 
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - List of different types of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40753306/c-sharp-list-of-different-types-of-objects)

Comment: This is not a valid C# syntax. Please provide real code.

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that your code does not compile, the items in `mylist` are all of type `a`, which means you will only be able to get `.x`. For accessing any other properties in the derived classes you would need to cast the list item to the related object e.g. `as b` to access `.y` and so on. Moreover, you probably need to make the class properties `public ` to allow them to be visible from the outside.

Comment: I am renewed my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed my former answer since you updated the question a lot.

The reason you don't see the property is because (as mentioned in a comment), the list only contains a "contract" to contain instances of the class `A`. Even if it also containes derrived classes (such as class `B`), it still isn't valid to access properties of `B`, because we can only ever be "certain" that the elements inside the list contain at least all the behavior and properties of `A`.

This is by design to ensure that we can't accidentally try accessing a property which doesn't exist for an instance of `A` during runtime.